# Flex Mobile Project: Numeric Keyboard

Tags: android, apache-flex, actionscript-3, mobile, blackberry-playbook

How do?

Edit the field with numeric keypad, not a full keyboard

my code:

```
    <s:TextInput text="{TransactionObject.cartao}" id="item" restrict="0123456789"  />
```

app for Android and playbook

Comment: it should work automatically in AIR.  is this an AIR application or browser-resident Flash RIA?

Comment: App air for playbook and android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numeric keyboard is not available in the current release of Adobe AIR.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the phone keypad but you can get numbers with this and you don't even need the *restrict* statement:

```
<s:TextInput softKeyboardType="{SoftKeyboardType.NUMBER}" />
```

If you don't import flash.text.SoftKeyboardType just use the literal "number". Available in Flex SDK 4.6.0.